# How to read RCA output from an mbed?

Tags: microcontroller, video, mbed, rca

I'm wanting to buy this [IR camera](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8773) but it says it has RCA output. Is it possible to read this into an mbed without external components(aside from a 12v power source)? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "RCA output" I assume they mean a composite video output.  In order to convert that into some sort of digital image that a microcontroller can use, you would need an extremely fast ADC, or simply a video decoder (i.e. one from [Maxim IC](http://www.maxim-ic.com/products/video/decoders.cfm), [Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/en/audiovideo-products/video-decoders/products/index.html), [TI](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=375&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T)) to tease out the image data.  Better yet, just get a camera with a digital output, as the digital-to-analog-to-digital path is a waste, as it's costly and performs worse.

NTSC scanlines are transmitted at 15.734 kHz with frequency content up to 4.2 MHz, impossible to handle with a standard microcontroller ADC which have sample rates of 1 Msps at the high end (NXP LPC1768 only has 200 ksps).  Furthermore, as Leon points out, your memory is extremely limited.  If you read just *one* QVGA (320 x 240) frame into memory at 8 bits/pixel, that's 76.8 kB, which exceeds the mbed's (NXP LPC1768's) on-board 64 kB RAM.

Comment: Heh. I hadn't thought about the actual size of one frame :/

Answer (score 0):

It's got a video output so you won't be able to use it with the mbed. It isn't fast enough and doesn't have enough memory.